# Javscript Math.Pow Multiplication

Tags: javascript, numbers, pow

I want to multiply the result of Math.Pow by a double (2 decimals). Here is an example:

```
const number = 2.01*Math.pow(10,9);
```

**Expected result:** 2010000000

**Actual Result:** 2009999999.9999998

What causes this slight deviation? Is there a solution to this problem without rounding the incorrect number?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a common problem in many languages:
https://0.30000000000000004.com/ 
A javascript solution could be: https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/

Comment: Javascript is not so good with calculation of big numbers, or saving many digits after zero. but for your particular case you can just write `2.01e9` which will do exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Also you can try to seperate the integer part from the decimal part, like so: `2*Math.pow(10,9)+.01*Math.pow(10,9)`